# What does “sheafs” mean in “The rays cut straight sheafs”?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, metaphors

This sentence is from *Atlas Shrugged*, depicting rays of light running through coils of steam enveloping a building:

> The rays of a few strong lights **cut straight *sheafs*** through the
>   coils.

Could anyone please explain to me how *sheafs* is to be understood here?

Does it denote the verb *sheaf*, as in *bundle*? That was the first thing to come to mind, but that seems wrong to me.

Comment: Does the author mean *shafts*?

Comment: No, she doesn't. I also checked on the internet whether the book may have a spelling error, and it doesn't seem so.

Comment: I like this question.  When I think of a "sheaf", I think of a bound clump of straight wheat stalks.  When I apply that to your quote, I imagine those stalks tumbling loosely through the air as the falling bundle of stalks forms sunbeams, kind of like an abstract-art painting.  I enjoyed the imagery.  I don't know if I classified this quote correctly, but that is how I envision it.  Have a nice day.

Comment: As it was Ayn Rand who wrote it, I think it's likely sheafs. Also, I came up with 0 results for *shafts*. So we need to presume she meant sheafs.

Comment: @medica: The only problem is that in this sentence, *sheafs* appears to be used as a plural noun, and the plural of the noun *sheaf* is *sheaves*.

Comment: I am not Ayn Rand. As it is she who wrote Atlas Shrugged, and not I, I will not be so bold as to try to correct her. Writers use language; they are not slaves to it. Doctors use medication/treatment guidelines; they are not slaves to them (experience matters.) There is practicality, and then there is art.

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be a distinctly technical meaning to *sheaf*. OED has

> **6.**
> **a.** *Physics and Math.* A bundle of rays, lines, etc. all passing through a given point.
>
> 1863   J. Tyndall *Heat* ix. §359. 302   A sheaf of calorific rays.
> 1885   C. Leudesdorf tr. L. Cremona *Elem. Projective Geom.* 22   A sheaf (sheaf of planes, sheaf of lines) is a figure made up of planes or straight lines, all of which pass through a given point (the centre of the sheaf).
> 1890   T. H. Eagles *Descriptive Geom.* 303   Sheafs of rays which in the case of a source of light..form a cone of which that source is the vortex.

Here's such an image. This is rays of sunlight through smoke, but I couldn't find a better representation of the dictionary definition.

[image: Rays of light through smoke]

[Sunlight in Woodland](http://photographygroup.blog.co.uk/2012/07/15/sunlight-in-woodland-14112722/) by [Keggy](http://www.blog.co.uk/user/keggy/)

Answer (score 3):

## Noun, not verb

*Sheafs* is here a plural noun, not a singular verb. There does exist a verb *sheaf* meaning to bind up into a sheaf or sheaves, but that is not what this instance of the word is.

And you’re right that *sheaf* has as its oldest sense a bundle of things, usually grains.  It appears metaphorically in the familiar Gospel tune [“Bringing In the Sheaves”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bringing_In_the_Sheaves).

What we have here in your quotation is another extended meaning.  The OED gives these pertinent senses:

> **1e.**  A cluster of jets of fire or water darting up together. (Cf. F. *gerbe*.)
>
> - **1811 Pinkerton** *Petral*. II. 535 — A thousand sheaves of fire blew up into the air, where, breaking and dispersing, they fell like a shower of stars.
> - **1857 Dufferin** *Lett. High Lat.* 125 — A shining liquid column, or rather a sheaf of columns wreathed in robes of vapour, sprung into the air.

But even more likely is this one:

> **6a.** *Physics* and *Math*. A bundle of rays, lines, etc. all passing through a given point.
>
> - **1863 Tyndall** *Heat* ix. §359. 302 — A sheaf of calorific rays.
> - **1885 Leudesdorf** *Cremona’s Proj. Geom.* 22 — A sheaf (*sheaf of planes, sheaf of lines*) is a figure made up of planes or straight lines, all of which pass through a given point (the centre of the *sheaf*).
> - **1890 Eagles** *Descript. Geom.* 303 — Sheafs of rays which in the case of a source of light..form a cone of which that source is the vortex.

### *Sheafs* or *Sheaves*?

As for the variant inflections, *sheafs* and *sheaves* alternate.  Both are current; I don’t know their relative popularity.

The *sheaves* form dates from the 16<sup>th</sup> century, and *sheafs* from the 17<sup>th</sup>.

In the north of Britain (northern England and Scotland) during the 19<sup>th</sup> century and perhaps later could be found dialectal plurals like *shoves* and *shoofs*.