# Single word for floating dust visible in sunlight

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word used in English for the visibility of dust particles floating in a stream of sunlight?

[image: real particles of dust in a sunbeam from the window]

<sub>*shutterstock.com*</sub>

Comment: They are called "motes."

Comment: I don't mean they actual particles themselves; I am referring to the phenomenon as a whole.

Comment: I wasn't very helpful, was I?  Sorry.  I can't think of a noun, just adjectives.  For an atmospheric phenomenon, "crepuscular rays."  For general optics,"volumetric lighting."  I hope that's better.

Comment: I was hoping for something more specific to seeing the small individual dust motes floating. Perhaps there is no such word. You have all been very helpful, thank you.

Comment: See this [related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181055/english-equivalent-of-komorebi-%E6%9C%A8%E6%BC%8F%E3%82%8C%E6%97%A5-sunshine-filtering-through-leaves/181057#181057)

Comment: Can you give an example sentence of how you would use such a word?

Comment: SWRs require a sentence with a gap where the required word might appropriately be used.

Answer (score 9):

There is an uncommon word, ***dustlight***, mainly appearing in literary works. It may serve as a single word for the whole phenomenon to describe the interplay between dust and light.

> ...there was no alternative but to count the remnant of the family savings in the feeable ray of moted **dustlight** that filtered down from the dingy opening.
>
> <sub>*The Possession of Immanuel Wolf: And Other Improbable Tales* by Marvin Kaye</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Beyond the dogs, the bottle, the old man, I saw santuario receding from view, glazed as it were by the scrim of ***dustlight***.
>
> <sub>*Trinity Fields* by Bradford Morrow</sub>

However, you can use ***mote*** to define the floating dust in sunlight:

> A particle of dust, esp. one of the innumerable minute specks seen floating in a beam of light; (contextually) an irritating particle in the eye or throat. *[OED]*

An example from *OED*:

> Moving freely about like the motes we see in the sunbeam.
>
> <sub>1880,   W. Wallace, *Epicureanism*</sub>

---

Scientifically, the phenomenon is *light scattering*.

You can check further details in the following links:

- http://megaanswers.com/how-are-we-able-to-clearly-see-dust-particles-in-a-sunbeam/
- http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept07/Li1/Li2.html

Answer (score 2):

The most widely-used **technical term** is 'scatter', and this is studied in Physics (Light), Astronomy, Meteorology and Hydraulics (measurement of flow). (click @ermanen's link)

Many **authors** say 'scintillate', for the light-effect, but always 'motes' are mentioned; so, scintillation by itself might not work.

> ***Home***   By Marilynne Robinson
>   A few motes of straw managed to scintillate in any shaft of sunlight.

Answer (score 2):

"Moted". As in, "The moted light" etc.

The definition from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/moted?locale=en):

> Of light: full of motes.

Comment: By the definition, this sounds exactly like what the OP wants. But it just does not sound good. 'Mote' is very old-fashioned and 'moted' barely recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

You could, circumstances being appropriate, call the dust *murk*.  Though it'd have to be sun shining into an otherwise gloomy place.  And it's not specifically the sun-illuminated dust, but all the dust.

An adjective for the air is *turbid*, in that it has suspended particles.

motes/sunbeam/Tyndall effect are all more appropriate given the photo.  Just adding some more terms in the event someone's not satisfied with the more straightforward words.

Answer (score -1):

Consider, ***skylight***

> The diffuse light from the sky, scattered by air molecules, as distinguished from the direct radiation from the sun.
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/skylight)

Answer (score -1):

https://www.britannica.com/science/Tyndall-effect

**Tyndall effect**, also called Tyndall phenomenon, scattering of a beam of light by a medium containing small suspended particles—e.g., smoke or dust in a room, which makes visible a light beam entering a window. The effect is named for the 19th-century British physicist John Tyndall, who first studied it extensively.

Comment: Related, but doesn’t answer the actual question.

Answer (score -2):

It's called a *colloid*! It's a chemical term that means evenly dispersed particles in gas solid or liquid.