# How do you describe bits of hay floating in the air?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, strong-verbs

I need to describe bits of hay puffing into the air from a rusty ute when it comes to a stop. Not sure how to describe it.

Comment: I think you just did describe it... Your description was certainly visually graphic enough for me to picture the scene in my head.

Comment: Thankyou... wasn't sure if it was descriptive enough. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Related question: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/253377/18655

Comment: Thankyou everyone for your help!