# What's a word for "Scattering of light by water droplets in the air" like the tyndall effect

Tags: vocabulary

In dark rooms, etc., when we see the path of light, dust in the air, what is that called?

Comment: "Diffusion", perhaps?

Comment: You may call it refraction/reflection, but, in truth, nobody knows what to call anything.  If you did, then you would know for sure how stuff truly works, on every level.  No one knows what light is.  No one has seen energy.

Comment: @G.Rem "No one has seen energy"? Um... the act of "seeing" something is to receive light energy on the retina. There's an entire Stack Exchange site, [Physics.SE], that would take issue with you on the science in your comment.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica Yes, but what does energy look like?  It forms particles/waves of light, and other things, in a field, but, what does it, itself, look like to be able to shift from one form to another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a single word used in English for the visibility of dust particles floating in a stream of sunlight?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253377/single-word-for-floating-dust-visible-in-sunlight)

Answer (score -1):

It's **called** *scattering*:

[Merriam-Webster *scattering*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scattering)

> : the random change in direction of the particles constituting a beam or wave front due to collision with particles of the medium traversed

[American Heritage Dictionary *scattering*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=scattering)

> 2. Physics The dispersal of a beam of particles or of radiation into a range of directions as a result of physical interactions.

Another word the might apply is *diffraction*:

[Merriam-Webster *diffraction*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diffraction)

> : a modification which light undergoes especially in passing by the edges of opaque bodies or through narrow openings and in which the rays appear to be deflected