# the sunlight that streams into a room through the window

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "the sunlight that streams into a room through the window, or a crack in the curtain or through a skylight"

Comment: This question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find it yet. In the meantime, closely related: [English equivalent of komorebi (木漏れ日) — “sunshine filtering through leaves”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181055/english-equivalent-of-komorebi-%E6%9C%A8%E6%BC%8F%E3%82%8C%E6%97%A5-sunshine-filtering-through-leaves)

Answer (score 10):

These are also called ***shafts of light***

> ***Shaft***: 5. Something suggestive of a spear or arrow in appearance or configuration, as:
>   a. A ray or beam of light.<sup>1</sup>

From [Shakespeare: The Two Traditions](https://books.google.com/books?id=MF5tf36_CvIC&pg=PA108&dq=shakespeare+%22shaft+of+light%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo0PLep6LJAhVD42MKHTRpAuQQ6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=shakespeare%20%22shaft%20of%20light%22&f=false):

> A shaft of light falls on the scene as the young-looking Fortinbras enters...

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub><sup>American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 9):

How about **sunbeams** or **rays of sunlight**? The meaning of these terms is a little broader than the specific context you're talking about, but I can't think of a better word.

Sunbeam [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sunbeam) is defined as:

> a beam, ray, or stream of sunlight.

Answer (score 3):

*Crepuscular ray*, while technically a reference to twilight sun, is often used figuratively for rays of sunshine in other situations.

Comment: I don't think many ordinary native speakers of English know the word "crepuscular" unless they are weather enthusiasts.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***streaks of sunlight***? [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22streaks+of+sunlight%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=fqxQVsO8LcrSUeK-qqAO#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22streaks+of+sunlight+filtered%22)

> streak:  a narrow band of light [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/streak)

Alternately, you might want to consider ***streams*** and ***flickers [of sunlight***]. [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22flickers+of+sunlight%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=hMRQVs36J8ysUdfztegO#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22flickers+of+sunlight+filtered%22)

> stream: a ray of light [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stream)
>
> flicker: a wavering light [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flicker)

***bars***, ***bands***, and ***strips*** are also possible options. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bars+of+sunlight%2Cstrips+of+sunlight%2Cbands+of+sunlight&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbars%20of%20sunlight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrips%20of%20sunlight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbands%20of%20sunlight%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

An additional term is ***god rays***, often used as a synonym of *crepuscular rays* in particular.

It is regularly used in the gaming industry to refer to the capability of a graphical engine to render [volumetric lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_lighting), by means of which light is seemingly scattered when travelling through non-solid objects (like air).

Although I believe it is commonly known in the CGI world, neither Merriam-Webster, Collins nor Dictionary.com have an entry for this term. Wikipedia's [Sunbeams page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunbeam#Crepuscular_rays) seems to be the most prominent semi-authoritative website mentioning the phrase.