# one word for collection of light beams

Tags: single-word-requests

In a cave, through a series of openings, beams of light fall inside. so that the darkness is punctuated with beams of light like so :

[image: Light filtering through trees]

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Forest-sun_01.JPG.

What is another name for this collection ?

> Sample Sentence - Sunlight fell in beams through the holes, drilled
>   into the sides of the cavern, at intervals so that it appeared to be a
>   "??" collection of dark interspersed with beams of light.

Note: I have seen [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181055/english-equivalent-of-komorebi-%E6%9C%A8%E6%BC%8F%E3%82%8C%E6%97%A5-sunshine-filtering-through-leaves) and while it talks about the name for the phenomenon, I'm talking about describing the effect.

Comment: A [*Grand Central Station*](http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/photo/2013/02/grand-central-terminal-turns-100/g01_01010201/main_900.jpg?1420510928)?

Comment: It seems you're not asking for a name for the collection of light beams, you're asking for a name for the total effect of the beams penetrating the darkness. Anyway, if you collect a number of light beams, you end up with just one..

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166430/what-does-sheafs-mean-in-the-rays-cut-straight-sheafs which gives an answer (it's a *sheaf* of rays).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call it an **array** of light beams.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/array

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, the phenomenom you're witnessing are **crepuscular rays**, but we know them by more colloquial terms:

- Sunbeams
- Sun rays
- Rays of sunshine

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crepuscular_rays
https://www.google.com/#q=Crepuscular+rays+cave

[image]